# In billboard.js, can I set the sequence of the legend?

Tags: billboard.js

In billboard.js, I use this line chart graph with time-series data.
It looks like the legend is automatically set in order as the data of the first day. However, I want to set the legend in descending order with the total max data.
To archive this, I made another array that has the max data set.
But I don't know what to do with this array.

The original data set looks like this.

```
columns: [
  ['x','2023-11-22','2023-11-23','2023-11-24'],
  ['A1', 631910, 569926, 613095 ],
  ['B1',  44580,  41792,  73143 ],
  ['C1',  53739,  49222,  49994 ],
  ['D1',  73721,  77590,  69982 ],
]
```

- Data set I made for legend sequence

```
[
 {key: 'A1', value: 631910},
 {key: 'D1', value:  77590},
 {key: 'B1', value:  73143},
 {key: 'C1', value:  49994}
]
```

So, for now, the legend shows in this sequence, 'A1-D1-C1-B1'.
But I want it to be like this, 'A1-D1-B1-C1'.

Can I set it like this? I read the official documents but couldn't find to change the order unlike the label has the order option.